# Trouble booting and installing Linux - Broken BIOS suspected?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, acpi

I have tried installing Ubuntu on my PC (msi PE60 6QE, Specs: nvidia GTX960M, i7, 16GB DDR4, Windows 10) via USB Drive. I have been trying for the past 3 days but it doesn't seem to work at all. The ISO file I am using is the 15.10 Ubuntu 64-bit version, works fine on my other PC.

When I enter the BIOS menu where I'm supposed to choose a device to boot from, I choose my USB stick with the Ubuntu 15.10 iso on it. I know that the USB stick works, since I had no trouble booting Ubuntu on my other PC (Lenovo). After choosing the stick, the menu pops up, where I am asked if I want to install the OS. I choose to install and multiple error messages pop up and the booting process is frozen.

```
    Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
    ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected
    nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUBO: 0x6013d4 0x00005700 (0x1c
    nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUBO: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1d
```

It has also occurred, that the Ubuntu pre-installation loading screen popped up and froze, but in every case these error messages popped up beforehand. I have tried changing the BIOS settings (UEFI with CSM, Disabling Fastbood, etc., tried quite every possible combinations) but nothing seemed to work. The PC either froze when the error messages popped up or after a few seconds in the loading screen. I also tried to add the command "set idle=nowait" in the grub, this was recommended on another thread with a similar issue, didn't work for me either.

It's the same scenario when I choose to try Ubuntu without installing. I also tried booting with a DVD, same problem. I have also updated my BIOS but that didn't help either, I get the same error messages. I hope someone can help me, so that I can finally enjoy using Ubuntu on my new PC.

Comment: I have almost the similar configuration of the HP Laptop. Is your secureboot is completely disabled in BIOS? In case of HP...that is a two step process to disable it.

Comment: Yes, I disabled it completely, but unfortunately I'm still getting a frozen screen with the error messages (I disabled the secure boot and left all the other settings to standard and also tried disabling fastboot and other options, always get a frozen screen either when the error messages pop up or shortly after entering the loading screen before installation) and I'm running windows 10, forgot to mention that before

Comment: Is it already installed and then you are having problem OR these problems you are getting at the time of install itself?

Comment: I'm getting the problems during the install itself, directly after hitting install after the USB or DVD boot. Also tried the noacpi command in the grub, got the same error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this could be the issue. Please setup the nomodeset before the installer starts doing anything. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded. For more details refer to this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Once the install is done you have to follow these steps(mine is also GTX 960M)
In the terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open it or Ctrl+Alt+F1 till F6) run this

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

This will remove any installed nvidia drivers.

Then install the new drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Okay, so I appended "nomodeset" at the end of the "linux" line in the grub terminal (pressing e in the menu with the options "try without install", install...), the last two error messages have disappeared, but the first two ones are still here and the screen still freezes with the error messages :/

Comment: @LST. good we are making some progress. Are you sure that after updating BIOS secure boot is completely disabled?

Comment: Yes, I double checked right now, Secure Boot is disabled, all other settings are on standard

Comment: I added nomodeset idle=nomwait and it worked, managed to enter the desktop :) will get rid of the drivers and update them, I'll let you know how it worked :)

Comment: @LST. Glad to know that it worked.

Comment: yes, but now I'm stuck with a purple screen, guess I'll have to open a new thread :) Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue... Did you find a solution?  Can you link to the "new thread".