# Purple Screen frozen upon reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 15.10, freeze

So yesterday I managed to install Linux, by adding the commands nomodeset and idle=nomwait to the grub. I'm still getting error messages, but at least I was able to enter the desktop (only in the same session as installation, everytime I reboot I get the frozen violet screen). ([Trouble booting and installing Linux - Broken BIOS suspected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736889/trouble-booting-and-installing-linux-broken-bios-suspected)) My PC specs: (msi PE60 6QE, nvidia gtx960M,16GB DDR4,intel i7). I am currently running the 15.10 64-Bit version of Ubuntu.
Now somehow after choosing to run Ubuntu from the grub menu upon rebooting, I get a violet, frozen screen.[Frozen violet screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLqI2.jpg) 
Sometimes when I don't add the commands "nomodeset" and "idle=nomwait", a black screen appears and from there nothing happens either. I have also tried starting Ubuntu in recovery mode, but it just freezes during the terminal is open, the last messages I get when running Recovery Mode are:

```
    BIOS EDD facility v.016 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
    EDD information not available
```

after these messages Recovery Mode freezes.

When I try to boot with generic I get the following lines before the screen freezes

```
    Booting command list

    Loading Linux 4.2.0-16-generic ...
    Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

and that's when it freezes in generic. same thing for generic (upstart). I'm just trying everything, nothing seems to work.

I'd be happy for every help.

Comment: When you boot from the LiveCD can you reach the desktop successfully ?

Comment: Hey,  when using my USB stick to boot, so when I actually use my USB stick to "install" Ubuntu it works, just have to add the nomodeset and idle=nomwait in the grub. However after installation, when I want to reboot using the Hard Disk partition I assigned to Ubuntu during the installation process, my screen freezes in the purple screen, I don't see any logo whatsoever, hope this is what you're asking for. it could be, because of my drivers. if I install linux and upgrade the drivers in the same session without rebooting, are these changes saved for the next boot?

Comment: So my problem actually is, that I can enter the Desktop to install Ubuntu, however when I reboot and try to access the Desktop the screen freezes after I choose to enter Ubuntu in the grub, basically I can only get in in the same session I install ubuntu. Reboot after install simply doesnt work and I can't enter ubuntu by using the partition on my Hard Drive dedicated to ubuntu.

Comment: @LST. Nvidia drivers installed as i mentioned in the other thread?

Comment: Yes, I managed to get in once, I take it was luck, pressed Ctrl+Alt+Del during the freeze, it rebooted and suddenly I managed to get into the desktop, updated the drivers as you told me but I get the same freeze when I reboot and Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't seem to fix it anymore, guess it was just a lucky shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixable.  On boot after BIOS screen tap SHIFT key to reach the grub screen.  up / down arrow to hightlight top OS release on list (newest one) and instead of hitting Enter press E to edit.

Use your arrow keys to move cursor to line which starts

```
linux /boot
```

put your additional kernel options at end of that line.  This fix is only good for current boot. Do this to confirm its the fix U need.  hit ctrl-X to proceed to finish current boot.

If above helps U reach the desktop, then to make above temp change permanent, one you reach desktop open a terminal window  ctrl-alt-t  and enter

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

or if you know vi

```
sudo vi  /etc/default/grub
```

edit the line starting with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

so it appears

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

do similar for additional kernel options.  Save your file then in terminal issue

```
    sudo update-grub
```

Let us know how you get on

PS.  On boot after BIOS tap left Shift key to bring up grub menu.  Is this possible ?  If so go into Recovery Mode on topmost OS then into graphics Failsafe mode.  Possible ?

Comment: I did that, added nomodeset and idle=nomwait at the end of the linux /boot line(http://askubuntu.com/questions/736889/trouble-booting-and-installing-linux-broken-bios-suspected/736893?noredirect=1#comment1094469_736893). without these commands id be stuck with a frozen black screen, now instead it's a frozen violet screen.

Comment: I managed to enter Recovery Mode without error, I could run failsafe graphic mode. If I choose to resume boot, the login screen pops up (finally!), however, when entering my password, the screen flashes and the login screen pops up again, it seems to be in a loop. When entering a wrong password, the circle next to the password field pops up and says the password is incorrect, quite normal. I also tried opening a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and entering my password and username there, but it says, that my login is invalid although I know it is correct, since I can see it in the login screen.

Comment: The wrong password is probably a separate issue.

Comment: Guess I'm opening a new thread again -.- tried to rewrite my account as sudo using visudo doesn't work and I can't find anything about this issue. Thank you for your time! was a big help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the "fix" for this was to finally boot on the last known good kernel (second from the top not marked recovery), which did boot, but reported errors. I clicked through the pop-ups letting the system fix itself... Then I rebooted, selected the main OS, and it booted fine.