# Can't run 16.10 from LiveUSB (it boots fine)

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, 16.10

I'm trying to run/install Ubuntu 16.10 from LiveUSB version (created with Rufus both in Iso and DD mode on both USBstick and external USB HDD.).
It boots fine to a grub menu when I can select Try/Install/troubleshoot. ( why don't I get the usual graphical interace with Ubuntu logo ? )
After selecting either of the options I get a violet screen and the USB stops reading, there are no messages on the screen, it goes straight to black or violet screen.

**THE LAST VERSION OF UBUTU THAT WORKS FOR ME ( in legacy mode) is 10.04 with 2.6.32 kernel. Starting with 10.10 and 2.6.35 it won't work.I'm also able to boot Trinity rescue kit with  2.6.37.1 kernel**

I've tried nomodeset and changing quiet to text mode but it always goes to violet screen.

Specs:

- cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U
- chipset: Intel Haswell-ULT rev. 09
- southbridge: H8x/P8x rev. C1
- ram: 4GB DDR3 - HMT351S6EFR8A-PB
- gpu: Intel integrated
- hdd: sshd Seagate ST1000LM014
- here's the complete lshw output : http://pastebin.com/FtQBtUxF

I've tried booting with nomodeset, idle=nomwait, nolapic, noapic, acpi=off, nousb. I've also tried Fedora and CentOS.

This is as far as I get with acpi=off, but the 0000:00:1d seems to be USB controller (http://pastebin.com/FtQBtUxF)
[image]

Comment: Did you by any chance verify the [hash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso/503788) of your ISO? It might be corrupted.

Comment: Yes I did. I've also tried another distributions with the same effect

Comment: Do you have a check disk for defects menu option on the grub menu you get?

Comment: What ISO did you download and from where?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/737012/purple-screen-frozen-upon-reboot and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I used the DVD from ubuntu.com and SHA256 checked it. I've tried nomodeset and idle=nomwait, also nolapic, noapic, acpi=off

Comment: Please provide a [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) link to the full output of `sudo lshw`

Comment: I finally got the lshw output form "trinity rescue kit" which was the only thing that ran on my machine (but only in legacy mode), whats curious, during the boot it told me that it cannot find itself (!) and I had to point it to sdb1 . http://pastebin.com/FtQBtUxF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purple Screen frozen upon reboot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/737012/purple-screen-frozen-upon-reboot)

Comment: This is what happened after 7 minutes ( but that's the end - I left it for an hour more ) https://goo.gl/photos/aabCWur21dCgH4pf9

Comment: Sorry, completely unfamiliar with your hardware and your lshw output doesn't help me much, but perhaps there is a [BIOS Update](https://www.medion.com/gb/service/download/) available for your system.  Do you have the same problem  with your system failing to assign an IRQ to  0000:00:1d if you boot from 16.04 live media? I'm wondering if this is kernel related or If there's an adjustment in your BIOS for EHCI/XHCI handoff that might make the difference

Comment: I've just checked (due to Trinity rescue kit booting fine) and the last working Ubuntu is 10.04 with 2.6.32 kernel. Starting with 10.10 with 2.6.35 kernel it stops working ;/ And yes, 16.04 yield the same error. I wrote to the manufacturer, because there is no BIOS update available on the website. My UEFI/BIOS is like poor relative of a regular BIOS, so there's not so much to mess with. – paniczklos 40 mins ago. Also between 10.04 and 10.10 there was a change in the graphics of the grub ( from black to violet, maybe it's connected to some changes inside).

Comment: It would be interesting to find out if it works properly with the early [version 3 kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A12.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support) shipped with Ubuntu 12.04.  But it seems you've tried that and the answer is no.  How old is this system? Retirement age perhaps?