# Ubuntu Doesn’t start

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10, acpi

I have a PC with Windows 10. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a second drive. When I was shutting down the computer from Ubuntu, it wouldn’t shut down but stuck with the message [number.number] reboot: System halted. 
So I tried what this video suggests: https://youtu.be/ZZBTSUbzT0g

Unfortunately not only this didn’t work for me, but I can’t get into Ubuntu anymore. It is stuck in a purple screen. I heard though the sound Ubuntu makes to inform me to fill my password.

Comment: Check this one out: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/737012/purple-screen-frozen-upon-reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737012/purple-screen-frozen-upon-reboot)

Comment: @SkepticBiped I went into Recovery Mode and i fixed it. But now i have the previous problem again. When i shut down the computer from Ubuntu it shows me the message [number.number] reboot: System halted.